# Repeat code if an error occured

Tags: go

I have a code which is doing a very long ETL operation. There are network problems sometimes. I want to catch the error `read tcp 10.10.10.10:32423 -> 20.20.20.20:2344: i/o timeout` and retry the operation again.

Here is my code:

```
for {
    err := mssql.Db.ProcessAllData(true, &processedAsutpIds, filename)
    if err == nil {
      fmt.Println("done.")
      os.Exit(0)
    } else {
      fmt.Println(err.Error())
      fmt.Println("!!!! Error occurred - sleep for 5 minutes")
      time.Sleep(time.Minute * 5)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to rewrite it in more idiomatic way ?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/ZQgQfmO-tK

Comment: @mkopriva looks like your code works correctly only with first error

Comment: you must have caught my comment before i corrected my typo (changed `if` to `for`). Here's an executable example https://play.golang.org/p/iFEsfOuvow. Basically this is Go's while loop; `for err != nil {...` = `while error do`.

Comment: @VonC, There are two right answers here. And I have check both answers as useful. Now I have changed the answer which I have accepted as most helpful for me to find solution.

Comment: @VonC, do you thing the second answer is incorrect ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might consider a retry function such as the one described in "[My favorite #golang retry function](https://blog.abourget.net/en/2016/01/04/my-favorite-golang-retry-function/)" by Alexandre Bourget:

```
    var signedContent []byte
    err := retry(5, 2*time.Second, func() (err error) {
        signedContent, err = signFile(unsignedFile, contents)
        return
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }
```

With the retry function being:

```
func retry(attempts int, sleep time.Duration, f func() error) (err error) {
    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        err = f()
        if err == nil {
            return
        }

        if i >= (attempts - 1) {
            break
        }

        time.Sleep(sleep)

        log.Println("retrying after error:", err)
    }
    return fmt.Errorf("after %d attempts, last error: %s", attempts, err)
}
```

Comment: Adding some backoff would't be a bad idea- simple `sleep*(i+1)` would do it.

Comment: @RexFuzzle Agreed. You even have more formized backoff policy with https://github.com/jpillora/backoff. Or https://github.com/cenkalti/backoff (as an algorithm that uses feedback to multiplicatively decrease the rate of some process, in order to gradually find an acceptable rate, which seems overkill here)

Comment: @RexFuzzle Note that the those libraries I mentioned above are improved in https://medium.com/@lestrrat/yak-shaving-with-backoff-libraries-in-go-80240f0aa30c and https://github.com/lestrrat-go/backoff

Answer (score 3):

The only improvement I see is:

```
for {
    err := mssql.Db.ProcessAllData(true, &processedAsutpIds, filename)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("done.")
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    fmt.Println("!!!! Error occurred - sleep for 5 minutes")
    time.Sleep(time.Minute * 5)
}
```

That is: Eliminate the 'else', since it's implicit.  `go vet` would tell you the same.  You should also use `gofmt` to correct indentation.

You might also want to check for specific errors, and only continue for network errors. But that's an application decision.